# Writing values to already existing worksheet

Tags: vb.net

I already have an Excel worksheet. How do I write some values to that worksheet from my VB application?

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is an Excel-VBA solution; however, someone has changed the question tag to VB.NET since.

```
Sub MySub()
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyBook.xls")
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.ActiveSheet

    xlSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Hello, world!"
End Sub
```

Comment: That is the full working code! Just tested it myself. Put it in a `Sub`. Heck, I'll spell it out for you. Note that if you are using `Option Explicit` (which is good practice) then you will have to declare the objects first.